# Replicate iOS App Updating procedure from App store in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I removed coreData in my app and use SQLite now. I need to create a new DB after the user updates their app.  I tested by installing the old version in App Store, and installing a new version from Xcode (without deletion). 
But how do I emulate the updating procedure just like updating from App Store? Can I do this emulation when running the project from Xcode?

For example, version 1.1.1 is on App Store.
First, I installed this version from App Store onto my phone.
Normally, the user will update next version from App store, right? 
But if I install 1.1.2 from Xcode, will this result be the same as updating from the App Store?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for my bad expression.
I add example, hope it will be more clear

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Yes user will update any changes from app store. Your upload will not effect user unless user update app from app store. You do not emulate updating procedure. If you could upload your new version to app store without problem, it means it works normally. If you want to do some tests you may use TestFlight. Test your app in there and then upload to app store.

Answer (score 0):

If the debug and release version of your app shares the same bundle id, it will be overwritten. Theoretically, yes for your question.

But I recommend against that. For testing in your case, you should upload the testable version to the Testflight and apply it to your current version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible in development if both the build has same bundle ID. It will replicate the appstore process as u want.I will also list down the other methods.

1. In development->with same bundle id
2. In **testflight**  by uploading the previous build and overriding with the latest one thats updating the app from testflight.
3. In **MDM**(App catalog)

Answer (score 0):

> But If I install 1.1.2 from Xcode, will this result same as updating from app store?

Yes. Each build on an already installed app, if the bundle match, will work the same as an app update. So if you want to test the DB update over and over, I would recommend to simply have the previous app code (1.1.1) in another branch that you can checkout, or a copy in another folder, and simply Run (1.1.1) and then run (1.1.2)

Alternatively you can use **TestFlight** to hold the previous version, so you can easily access the version (1.1.1), and then run the (1.1.2) from Xcode.

---

Also, you can change your build configuration from Debug to Release. So it will be the same as the App Store.

Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Build Configuration -> Release

[image]